# How to handle dependent action creators in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Let's say I have a REST API to edit a user profile.
There are two methods concerned here

- a method to update the user profile;
- a method to get the current profile's completion score.

Of course, when the user updates his profile, I want to fetch the completion score.

Here is my (naive ?) way to do this with `redux` and `redux-thunk` action creators

```
function updateProfileAction(userId, profile) {

  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch("PROFILE_UPDATE", /*...*/)
    api.updateProfile(userId, profile)
      .then(repsonse => dispatch("PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS", /*...*/))
      // ▼ triggers the action that fetch the completion score
      // this is the line that bugs me
      .then(() => fetchProfileCompletionAction(userId))
  }

}
```

What bugs me with this line:

- it **breaks the single responsibility principle** (the `udpateProfileAction` is suddenly responsible for also fetching the completion);
- it is **not fractal** (if I want to add a feature that depends on the profile update, I need to modify, yet again, that piece of code.

For example if, for some reason, I don't want to display the completion anymore (say I remove the component that displays it) and forget to remove this line of code, the `fetchCompletion` will be triggered but will never be used in a graphical component).

I was thinking, maybe in the component that consumes the completion being fetched, I could subscribe to the store and `dispatch` at this moment. This would allow me to code in a **more reactive way**

```
function Completion(props) {

  props.store.subscribe(state => {
    //check if profile has changed
    dispatch(fetchProfileCompletionAction(userId))
  })

  return <div> {props.completion} </div>
}
```

Is this a good idea? Is there a better way to do this? Also I guess checking that the relevant state has changed is not really trivial with this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a few tests an researches I tried `redux-cycles` as a replacement of `redux-thunk` which handles that kind of problems very nicely.

It allowed me to subscribe to the profile being changed and request the completion against the server when the profile is updated. Which is **way more semantically correct** than what I was doing in the initial question.

Here is what the code looks like

```
function main(sources) {
  const updateProfileRequest = sources.ACTION
    .filter(action => action.type === "UPDATE_PROFILE")
    .map(action => ({ /* update profile request object */))

  const profileUpdateSuccess$ = sources.HTTP
    .select("profileUpdate")
    .flatten()
    // when a profile request is successful, I want to warn the store
    .map(response => ({ type: "UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS", profile: response.body })

  const fetchCompletionRequest$ = sources.STATE
    .map(state => state.profile)
    // whenever the state changes, I want to fetch the completion
    .compose(dropRepeats())
    .mapTo({ /* fetch profile request object */ })

  return {
    HTTP: xs.merge(udpateProfileRequest$, fetchCompletionRequest$),
    ACTION: profileUpdateSuccess$
  }
}
```

### The semantic with `redux-thunk`

In my first attempt, the semantic of the code is:

**When the user request for an update of his profile**: send the update request to the server **AND** when the response arrives dispatch the `profile_update_success` **AND** send the request to fetch the new completion value

And that was the **responsibility of a single component**.

### The semantic with `redux-cycles`

Now, with `redux-cycles` here is what my code means:

**When the user requests for an update of his profile**: send the update request to the server

**When an update profile response arrives**: send the `UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS` action

**When the store's profile is updated**: send the request to get the new completion

Those three actions are completely decoupled and have an individual semantic.

Notice how the second step is "When **an** update profile response arrives" and not "When **the** update profile response" :)

So in the end, I am not solving the **non fractal** issue, but I think this is in the very nature of `redux` so there is not much I can do about this, but at least I have a much more **reactive system**.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer your current solution.

I think of it like this:

- Actions represent something that occurs in the system
- State may change as the result of an action
- Components subscribe to changes in the state they render

With this philosophy, if an extra action get raised that no reducers are looking for, doesn't matter.  If some state changes that no components will render, doesn't matter.

With your second suggestion, as you suggested, it will be difficult to determine if the state has changed as you will only have the current state, without the previous state, to determine this.

If you do want to do something like this, you could use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) and wire the component up with react-redux so the state changes come in through props, for example:

```
class ProfileSuccessNotification extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!this.props.success && nextProps.success) {
      this.props.showNotification(nextProps.userId)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.show ? <p>{this.props.userId} fetched successfully!</p> : null
  }
}

// map from where ever in your state
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userId: state.profile.userId,
  success: state.profile.loaded,
  show: state.profileNotification.show
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showNotification: (userId) => dispatch(fetchProfileCompletionAction(userId))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileSuccessNotification)
```

Of course, you can also have multiple reducers react to the same action.  I'm not sure what the difference is between `PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS` and the action raised by `fetchProfileCompletionAction` would be, so perhaps you just want to update 2 pieces of the state when `PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS` get raised, negating the need to chain a second action at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I understand your point of view, I have a very reactive prog background and this kind of thing really bugs me. It breaks the single responsibility principle and is totally **not fractal** (meaning if I want to add a new feature depending on the profile, it cannot be standalone, I need to change that piece of code). Also I am not dispatching in the `render` but in the `store.subscribe` callback, which is very different

Comment: I realize my question might be too opinionated for SO, maybe I should close it, what do you think?

Comment: You are correct about not being in the render (obviously not enough coffee today), I'll edit my answer to remove that.  As for closing, I don't mind questions wanting guidance on patterns or options, but I agree that it might be hard to find a accepted answer.